# How to remove rows from a csv file for which values of certain attributes are the same

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file. In that file if the values of first, 5th and 13th attributes are the same, then the rows will be considered as duplicates. in that case duplicate rows are to be removed. How to do that in python?

I wrote a code but it seems the code falls in infinite loop:

```
import csv

rows = csv.reader(open("items4.csv", "r"))
newrows = []
i=0
for row in rows:
   if(i==0):
      newrows.append(row)
      i=i+1
      continue
   for row1 in newrows:
      if(row[1]!=row1[1] and row[5]!=row1[5] and row[13]!=row1[13]):
         newrows.append(row)
writer = csv.writer(open("items5.csv", "w"))
writer.writerows(newrows)
```

Comment: do your csv has any headers ?

Comment: @RehanAzherYes it has

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change your logic ever so slightly to introduce a flag, like this:

```
for row1 in newrows:
   if row[1]==row1[1] and row[5]==row1[5] and row[13]==row1[13]:
       break
else:
   newrows.append(row)
```

The problem with your initial code was that you kept adding the row into `newrows` if it did not match any of the rows inside, this effectively extended `newrows` indefinitely since you keep adding values that satisfied: `row[1]!=row1[1] and row[5]!=row1[5] and row[13]!=row1[13]`

Comment: Also if you're using the `found` flag, you can effectively remove the `if` statement checking if it is the first row since you're already validating any rows inside `newrows` inside your second loop anyways. cheers!

Answer (score 1):

@Clarence already gave a great answer.

Just as an alternative, pandas makes these things much easier when things get more complicated.

Let's say you have the columns that you want to consider in a list, called *col_list*

```
import pandas as pd
# --- About read_csv ---
# header and delimiter are two arguments to consider for read_csv
df = pd.read_csv('path/to/your/file.csv') 

# --- About drop_duplicates ---
# inplace being True changes the df itself rather than creating a new DataFrame
# subset takes the labels of columns to consider, you call them with df.columns so df.columns[col_list] will give you your desired column labels
df.drop_duplicates(subset=df.columns[col_list], inplace=True) 

# --- Important Reminder!!! ---
# Don't forget that Python indices start with 0 not 1, therefore first columns should be denoted as 0 in your col_list

# --- Write your file back ---
df.to_csv('path/to/your/new_file.csv')
```